# What are the diseases that affect Angelica?

Tags: diseases

I've never grown angelica, or seen anyone else growing it.

What diseases should I look for when growing it?
How do I cure the disease to make the plant healthy again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angelica atropurpurea is native to MN.

Easily grown in medium to wet soils in full sun to part shade.

A large herbaceous perennial which grows from 3-10' tall with smooth, dark purple or purple-blotched stems. Native to wet areas of Minnesota Features tiny greenish-white to white flowers arranged in large, compound umbels Flowers bloom in summer.

[According to Missouri Botanical it has no major pest or disease.](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=y480)

It might get powdery mildew at the end of the season. Which is fine, because it is at the end of the season.  Just go ahead and cut it to the ground.  That is better than trying to treat a plant that is trying to wind down for long winter sleep.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, you are in USDA zone 4a -this plant is only hardy in zones 5 - 9, some sites say zone 9 only, and if you''re growing it for the roots, it takes three years for the plant to mature, so the biggest problem you'll have is keeping it alive at all for any length of time. Growing in pots is not an option because it puts down a very long taproot, which also means, in places where the climate is right for it, it's difficult to eradicate. https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/herbs/angelica/growing-chinese-angelica-plants.htm

Comment: I got the one that's native to MN and edible.

Comment: What is its proper name? I don't know of any other plant that's known as dong quai or angelica...

Comment: https://plants.usda.gov/core/profile?symbol=ANGEL the specific one i'm growing is angelica alexanders

Comment: Okay, but which one - I don't recognise the map of the States so can't work out which one grows naturally where you are....

Comment: https://lovelygreens.com/wild-food-alexanders/

Comment: Alexanders is Smyrnnium olusatrum - its a mediterranean plant that grows wild in warmer regions. Even in the UK (zone 7 and 8 mostly) it struggles in cold winters, and is largely only found in the milder coastal regions or in the south and west. It won't get through the winter where you are - its a biennial plant, so won't be much use to you. It is not in the same family of plants as angelica, is entirely unrelated.

Comment: The MN water garden society sold it to me, and they said it would survive MN winters, so I'll trust them. It specifically states zones 3-9.

Comment: you sure we're talking about the same plant? Dong quai is  certainly not Alexanders... its not clear which plant you actually mean, because you've only given a common name.

Comment: when i googled angelica it came up with dong quai, so i'm as sure as the google results are.

Comment: ok, but then you provided a link to Alexanders, a different plant... its impossible to answer your original question without knowing precisely which plant you're talking about, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77673/discussion-between-black-thumb-and-bamboo).